# Making SVG Image Responsive Using Raphael

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

I have an SVG image of African Continent, that I would like to make responsive,
the image is 1500px by 1500px. and I use the [ImportSVG](https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import) library extension of Rapheal to utilize my SVG:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Content/Blank_Map-Africa.svg",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (svgXML) {
            var paper = Raphael(150, 150, 1500, 1500);

            var newSet = paper.importSVG(svgXML);

            var world = paper.setFinish();
        }
    });
});
```

I have found this [library](http://www.shapevent.com/scaleraphael/), but not sure how I would include it in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can i scale Raphael js elements on window resize using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176396/how-can-i-scale-raphael-js-elements-on-window-resize-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a similar question:

[Cross-browser SVG in responsive or fluid layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983749/cross-browser-svg-in-responsive-or-fluid-layout?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I believe using the [Article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/02/clown-car-technique-solving-for-adaptive-images-in-responsive-web-design/) mentioned would solve your issue